# How to check if Append Function is activated/enabled on Linux server

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

I have an issue with an API from an external provider. Their API should do an FTP push to an external server. However, it is failing. They say that the Append Function needs to be active/enabled as according to them - the push is failing because the file can't be created on the server (I realize that Append would just add to an existing file). I am running a Linux CentOS6 and am able to create new files via PHP. Can't seem to find that function anywhere online - does it even exist on Linux and if yes - how can I confirm it's enabled?

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me how the systems are connected and what protocols or software are actually in use.

Comment: they're using FTP not a web service, what FTP server is your web site running?

Comment: The situation is: there is a solar panel inverter which creates a CSV file every 15mins grabbing current power production details etc. The inverter has the API for pushing that CSV over FTP to an external server where those information can be further processed. I don't have alternative options. Any idea how I could test if "put" and "append" are enabled on my server? I'm sorry I don't have any more details - the API provider just asks for the "Append" function to be enabled on the FTP server. Can you advise?

Comment: Does this question help? [vsftpd not allowing anonymous users to append to existing files](http://serverfault.com/questions/346155/vsftpd-not-allowing-anonymous-users-to-append-to-existing-files-appe)

Comment: Sadly no as the user isn't accessing anonymously. I'm just wondering how to check for the Append function - if it's enabled?

Comment: Do you have an ftp client installed? Try running it, connect to the server, log in, then run the command `append localfile remotefile`. Do you need to automate this check, or just do it one time manually?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - thanks! how would I run this in say Filezilla? Just a single check to confirm server config.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to do that in FileZilla. I usually use the regular command-line ftp client.

Comment: how about telling us which ftpd you are running?  that way we might be able to tell you which features it supports, or how to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append works by default for a stock `vsftpd` install on Centos with an authenticated login.

```
$ sudo yum -y install vsftp ftp
...
$ mkdir ~/tmp; cd ~/tmp
$ echo hi > foo
$ ftp localhost
...
ftp> put foo
...
ftp> ^Z
$ cat ~/foo
hi
$ fg
append foo foo
...
ftp> ^Z
$ cat ~/foo
hi
hi
$
```

You'll need to debug the FTP connection (e.g. with wireshark) and review the server logs (under `/var/log`) to see what is going awry.